# Netbeans Xdebug is not responding

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to debug my PHP code on my local machine. When I start to debug, script doesn't response any more.

Netbeans successfully handles the connection, xdebug logs shows that connection is established too. But browser is waiting busy.

I have tried Netbeans 7.2.1 and 7.4 and xdebug Version v2.1.0,v2.2.3 and v2.3.0dev

Do you have an advice?

Here is my configuration

> zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug_ready.so
>   xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
>   xdebug.remote_port = 9001 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
>   xdebug.remote_mode = req xdebug.profiler_enable=0
>   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
>   xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug" xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"

Here is the log :

> Log opened at 2013-12-28 22:43:47 I: Connecting to configured
>   address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001. I: Connected to client. :-)
>   -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   fileuri="file:///var/www/pnp/pnpdev/index.php"
>   language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0"
>   appid="22843"
>   idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine
>   version="2.3.0dev"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick
>   Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright
>   (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
>
> <- feature_set -i 267 -n show_h&#305;dden -v 1
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="feature_set" transaction_id="267"
>   status="starting" reason="ok"><error
>   code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing
>   options]]></message></error></response>
>
> <- feature_set -i 268 -n max_depth -v 3
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="feature_set" transaction_id="268"
>   feature="max_depth"
>   success="1"></response>
>
> <- feature_set -i 269 -n max_ch&#305;ldren -v 30
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="feature_set" transaction_id="269"
>   status="starting" reason="ok"><error
>   code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing
>   options]]></message></error></response>
>
> <- feature_set -i 270 -n max_data -v 2048
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="feature_set" transaction_id="270"
>   feature="max_data"
>   success="1"></response>
>
> <- breakpoint_set -i 271 -t l&#305;ne -s enabled -f
>   file:///var/www/pnp/pnpdev/index.php -n 21
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="271"
>   state="enabled" id="0"></response>
>
> <- run -i 272
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="run" transaction_id="272"
>   status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
>
> <- stop -i 273
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot;
>   command="stop" transaction_id="273"
>   status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>
>
> Log closed at 2013-12-28 22:44:05

Answer (score 4):

The log shows that Xdebug and netbeans are communicating. There is even a smiley face. For some *odd* reason, instead of sending "line", netbeans sends: "lıne" (&#305 is actually Å) which is not a valid type. Xdebug should reject that, but it seems to simply allow it and not raise an error. I filed a ticket for that: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1025

However, *why* netbeans is sending that, you'll have to ask the netbeans team (file a bug?!)